# My bitcoin change

Tags: change

I am new to this.I have sent out bitcoin over the blockchain before and saw that the hash just took a fee. However the other day it took out over.95 of a bitcoin when wanting to only send 0.04 of a bitcoin to binance. I was told they send you an adress for change, which I didn,t know. I saw my ledger nano scrolling an address. Was this the change coming back? Since I saw such a large amount I wasn't sure that my coin would be going out to someone else or me. I clicked on the x instead of the checkmark. Did I lose my coin? Can I get that address back. can I go to that blockchain transaction and have it sent to my wallet since it says unspent.Please help. Once again did I lose my Bitcoin can I go back and have it sent to me from the original transaction?Can I get it back with the original address rather then the new?

Answer (score 0):

I marked this as a duplicate, but here is some specific info to help calm your nerves. Don't worry, from the sounds of things you did not lose any coins :)

Your ledger nano would not require you to 'accept' the change being returned to you, this would happen automatically in the wallet when you send any transaction. No action required on your part (beyond sending the transaction itself), in fact almost every bitcoin transaction will include a change output that pays back to the owner of the input, this is inherent to the function of bitcoin.

If your transaction says 'unconfirmed' that is normal, and means that it has not yet been included in a block. Depending on the fee paid, it should confirm in due time, and then your reported wallet balance should simply be `(balance before transaction) - (payment sent)`.

Comment: Would the ledger nano scroll the address coming to me? If so I might have pressed the x instead of the check.Would I still get the coin back.

Comment: This page has details on how to send a transaction using your ledger: https://support.ledgerwallet.com/hc/en-us/articles/360006353314 . If you clicked an 'x', chances are you simply declined to send the transaction in the first place (the screen was likely asking you to confirm the *recipient's* address, not your own change address). I have never seen any wallet software that forces you to 'confirm a change address' in order to receive your change, in fact that would be a positively horrible implementation. From the info you've provided, I am reasonably sure your coins are safe.

Comment: When my change was going to come back to me an address scrolled on my ledger nano, because I hit the X the transactions for the change return seems to have not worked.Can I retrieve my change again by going up to the same transaction on the blockchain and get the change?

Comment: Is your balance now lower than expected? Again, **there is no action required to ‘have your change sent to you’**. This happens automatically if a transaction is sent, it is a part of (nearly) every transaction.

Comment: I think the ledger nano won't allow incoming info with out verfiying the address which by mistake I hit the x which says its not verified.Can you check that out.

Comment: The ledger will display the address you are *paying to*, and ask you to confirm that. It will not ask you to confirm the change address. Once you confirm payment address, the hanger address will be automatically generated and managed by the software.

Comment: ^typo above. That should read *"the **change** address will be automatically generated and..."*